# principal.php:133 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '$_GET'

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando agregar un desplazamiento infinito a mi página web (estoy usando php 8.2), pero la consola devuelve este resultado cuando quiero ejecutar el script:

> principal.php:133 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identificador inesperado '$_GET'

He probado muchos métodos, incluido ver tutoriales, pero no puedo encontrar una manera que resuelva este problema. No conozco mucho sobre JavaScript, por lo que esto realmente está siendo un poco dificil.

Este es el JS:

```
var page = (int)$_GET['page'];

  // Function that makes an AJAX request to get more posts
  function getMorePosts(page, numPosts) {
    // Realiza una petición AJAX al servidor
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/publicaciones.php?page=' + page + '&num_posts=' + numPosts);
    xhr.send();

    // When the AJAX request has finished, add the new posts to the element containing the posts
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var publicaciones = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        // Add the new posts to the element containing the posts
        for (var i = 0; i < publicaciones.length; i++) {
          document.querySelector('#center').innerHTML += publicaciones[i];
        }

        // Refresh the current page
        window.history.pushState({}, null, '/publicaciones.php?page=' + (page + 1));
      }
    };
  }

  // Add the getMorePosts() function to the scroll event of the element containing the posts
  document.querySelector('#center').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    // Gets the height of the element containing the posts
    var height = document.querySelector('#center').scrollHeight;

    // Gets the height of the window
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    // Checks if the user has reached the end of the posts list
    if (height <= windowHeight + document.querySelector('#center').scrollTop) {
      // Load more posts
      getMorePosts(page, 50);
    }
  });
```

Code that collects the publications:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$numPost = 3;
$compag = 1;

$TotalReg = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM post");
$totalr = mysqli_num_rows($TotalReg);
$TotalRegistro = ceil($totalr / $numPost);
$IncrimentNum = (($compag + 1) <= $TotalRegistro) ? ($compag + 1) : 0;
$publicaciones = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3";

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $_GET['page'] = 1;
}
$resultado_publicaciones = mysqli_query($mysqli, $publicaciones);
while ($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_publicaciones)) {


    $userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $lista['userID']);
    $usuariob = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID = '$userID'");
    $use = mysqli_fetch_array($usuariob);
    $profilePic = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM archivos WHERE USERID = '$userID'");
    $profilePic2 = mysqli_fetch_array($profilePic);


    /*$fotos = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE publicacion = '$lista[ID]'");
    $fot = mysqli_fetch_array($fotos); */

?>
```

Comment: Buenas, Emmanuel, el error se produce porque estás intentando mezclar PHP y Javascript en el mismo código, ese $_GET.  Para recuperar los parámetros de la URL en Javascript [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979975/2553194) puedes encontrar varias soluciones

Comment: Ya arreglé el error de consola, pero sigue sin funcionar el scroll infinito

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta, quitando ese error si ya lo has solucionado y explicando qué te ocurre ahora. Por otro lado no estoy viendo que pagines al realizar tu consulta en la parte PHP. Creo que no has seguido fielmente el tutorial que sea. [Aquí](https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html) tienes un ejemplo de paginar en PHP con MySQL. Una vez tengas eso, es cuando deberías intentar enlazarlo con Javascript.